# Constructing a bi-linear map relating Tensor Product "like" object to a module for ANY subgroup of a free group defined by relations using only +?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, group-homomorphism, free-modules

I'm going over the construction of Tensor Products using modules as in Dummit and Foote. So they have explained Tensor Products as motivate by a desire to "extend" scalar multiplication to a module which another is embedded in. Specifically they take $R$-module $N_R$ and look to embed it in $L_S$ an $S$-module with $R \leq S$.They then take an $S$-module homomorphism $\phi:F[S \times N_R]/H \rightarrow L_S$ where $F[S \times N_R]/H$ turns out to be the Tensor Product itself and $\phi$ turns out to be the unique bi-linear map (which I saw in the universal property for Tensor Products).

I noticed that the construction seems to work for $H$ a subgroup because the relations that define $H$ are expressed as elements of $F[S \times N_R]$ being added to each other. So when you conjugate any $(a,b)$ on $H$ it will certainly be normal as in $(a,b) + H - (a,b) = H$. If this is the case does this imply that any subgroup defined by relations which explicitly use addition in a similar way will define something besides a Tensor Product when modding out $F[S \times N_R]$?

**Clarifying the Question**:
Let $R, S$ be rings such that $R\leq S$ and let $N_R$ be an $R$-module. Let $L_S$ be an $S$-module.  Then the Tensor Product is defined by the module homomorphism

$\phi: F[S \times N_R]/H \rightarrow L_S$

where $H$ is the relation$\langle(s,n_1 + n_2) - (s, n_1) + (s, n_2),  (s_1 + s_2,n) - (s_1,n) + (s_2,n),  (sr, n) - (s, rn)\rangle$

But suppose there was another relation $K$ which also relied totally on addition to define the relation. Would $\psi: F[S \times N_R]/K \rightarrow L_S$ also define a Tensor Product or maybe something different?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is exactly. Yes, if you take any submodule $H$ of the free module $F[S\times N_R]$, you can define a quotient $F[S\times N_R]/H$, which will be generated by elements that you might call $s\otimes n$ if you want. It usually won't be very interesting, and won't satisfy any kind of blinearity condition, unless you put those relations in $H$ (which leads to the tensor product).

Comment: @CaptainLama so you are saying that because any subgroup of a free group on the direct product of abelian group is itself abelian than H is always normal in that free group? So this means any such homomorphism will work? Is there  a stricter condition besides bi-linear that can happen? Is there a looser condition that gives something interesting? I'm not interested in reproducing something just like the Tensor Product so much as using that same type of construction to produce anything that isn't trivial.